# Unable to point JAVA_HOME variable to the location of the java installation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm creating a basic spring application on intelliJ ultimate (windows version) and my ** JAVA_HOME variable is apparently not pointing to the right JDK**.
I checked my project structure, and my JDK home path was specified as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181". I specified the same path when I created a  JAVA_HOME variable in my environment variables. I made sure to close the terminal on intelliJ and run another one, but I still get that error. Any input as to what I could be doing wrong would be  much appreciated. 
I have attached a few snippets to describe my situation better. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To rule out the obvious thing - did you stop an earlier command-line, and open a new one, after you set that system property on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I just tried what you said again to confirm, and I still get that error

Comment: In your CMD shell type "echo %JAVA_HOME%".  That will tell you what the environment variable is set to in the CMD shell ... which is the only thing that `mvnw` actually knows about.

Comment: I did and its the same as the directory pointed above.